# How do I test in IE 9 on OS X?

Tags: macos, testing, browser, virtualization

I'd prefer not to spend any money. I know Microsoft used to maintain some .VPC images that could be imported into VirtualBox/etc., but I was reading another StackOverflow that said this doesn't work anymore -- an activation is forced.

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a project named `ievms` on Github that sets up VMs for IE6, IE7, IE8 and IE9 (all on separate virtual machines).

Instructions (taken from the project page [here](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms)):

```
 1. Install VirtualBox
 2. Download and unpack ievms
   - Install IE versions 6, 7, 8 and 9.
        curl -s https://raw.github.com/xdissent/ievms/master/ievms.sh | bash
   - Install specific IE versions (IE7 and IE9 only for example):
        curl -s https://raw.github.com/xdissent/ievms/master/ievms.sh | IEVMS_VERSIONS="7 9" bash
 3. Launch Virtual Box
 4. Choose ievms image from Virtual Box.
 5. Install VirtualBox Guest Additions (pre-mounted as CD image in the VM).
 6. IE6 only - Install network adapter drivers by opening the `drivers` CD image in the VM.
```

More details can be found on the [project page](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms).

Comment: ievms.sh is a very handy script. (Thank you author Greg Thornton)
It saved me a lot of time comparing to manual work I used to do before.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you can directly download some VMs, from [here](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools).
Hope it helps!